# JavaScript "load" event listener is not triggered when page is visited from a relative path link

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, listener, onload-event

I wrote a chrome extension that runs a function called `find_agent`, on every page load.
However, when navigating between the site pages the function is not called again, unless refreshing the destination page.
All pages have the same domain.

manifest.js:

```
{
"name": "FindAgent",
"version": "0.99",
"manifest_version": 2,
"content_scripts" : [
    {
        "matches": ["https://www.[DOMAIN HIDDEN].com/[PATH HIDDEN]*"],
        "js": ["find_agent.js"],
        "css": ["style.css"]
    }
]}
```

find_agent.js:

```
function find_agent()
{
   ...
}
window.addEventListener('load', function ()
{
    find_agent()
})
```

Comment: What site are you testing it on? If the site is an SPA of sorts (so all views are loaded dynamically and there is actually no reloading of the window), that will explain what you’re encountering.

Comment: The links are simple <a href> with relative path that matches the pattern

Comment: Since `"run_at": "document_idle"` is the default value, you might not even need to rely on window onload. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/content_scripts/#run_time

Comment: [Is there a JavaScript / jQuery DOM change listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39508954)